Can I activate a venv that was installed with Windows (on a cloud drive) from a Mac?
I have a Django project in Dropbox, I mostly work on it from my Windows 11 Surface on work breaks, from which it was installed, but I have a Mac at home and want to be able to work on the same project from the Mac when I'm off. This must be possible, but I haven't found an answer so far on the Web. Can I reinstall the venv without blowing up the project? Will it work properly if I install a second venv, or could even that blow it up? I really don't want to screw up the project and have to re-do it.

I installed a second venv from bash(zsh) and it's working fine. Both venv directories are in the project and hidden, they have the same versions of Python3 and Django and it doesn't appear to have any effect on the project. There is probably not a better solution, but if you have one, please give it.

For anyone else looking at this, the only problem was that when I went to install Django in the bash environment it kept saying the requirements were already met (from a global install), after I upgraded pip I was able to re-install Django into the environment and everything is working.
